# Why is this FireDAC SQL Server query with parameters failing?

Tags: delphi, firedac

This is my first time doing a query with parameters. (Using Delphi Seattle and FireDAC in SQL Server)

(I'm planning on using DML once I get this working.)

Why am I getting this error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
>   [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ':'.

with this query:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDParam: TFDParam;
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE TestTable (Column1 Int)';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO TestTable (Column1) VALUES (111)';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;  // works fine

  FDParam := FDQuery1.Params.Add;
  FDParam.Name := 'Column1';
  FDParam.DataType := ftInteger;
  FDParam.Paramtype := ptInput;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO TestTable (Column1) VALUES(:Column1)' ;
  FDQuery1.ParamByName('Column1').AsInteger := 222;
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;  // FAILS 
end;
```

Comment: Comment the code that creates the param and run again. Does the error go away? Most DB drivers will parse the SQL and create the parameters automatically, and using `AsXXXX` will handle the ParamType. I've never had to create a parameter in code with any DB components using Delphi.

Comment: I've run the above code on my laptop using a very old SQL server 7 **and** SQL server 2000 and both run perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ken and Johan: thanks for your comments.

Someone here had set the *connection's* ResourceOptions.ParamCreate and ParamExpand to false.

Overriding that in the FDQuery eliminated the problem.

Thank you again.

Comment: Then, please acecpt this as the answer, to help future searchers.